# get file type of uploaded file when FileReaderService is used in html5

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

I am trying to detect file type of uploaded document. For this I have created an instance of "FileReaderService". I am doing something like this:

var reader = FileReaderService.createReaderInstance(),
            fileData = angular.copy(newFile);

```
      reader.onload = function (event) {
        scope.loaded(event, scope.files[index]);
      }.bind(scope);

      fileData.file = file;
      fileData.fileType = scope.fileType(fileData);
```

This is working fine for pdf and images but when it comes to docx, sheet and pptx. this is not working fine
Pleas help me out with this.

Comment: can you do console.log(fileData) & paste it in question. It'll help solving your issue

Comment: @Shantanu thank you for your response but I have resolved the issue and posted back the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it. The place where I am comparing file type I have done a mistake there:
earlier doc was used in now docx is used.
Now file type of docx, pptx and styles is following:

```
sheet: vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
docx: vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
pptx: vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
```